# Unresolved externals cv::flip cv::imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

Can not set OpenCV in VS 2017. What do I do wrong? And yes I have red all other posts.

**CODE:**

```
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

    using namespace cv;

    void main() {
    Mat src;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> src;
        flip(src, src, 2);
        imshow("dd", src);

        waitKey(0);
    }}
```

**LIBS I included:**

- opencv_highgui401.lib
- opencv_core401.lib
- opencv_videoio401.lib

**LIB DEPENDEICES:**

- C:\OpenCV\OpneCV_bin\install\x64\vc15\bin
- C:\OpenCV\OpneCV_bin\install\x64\vc15\lib

**ADDITIONAL INCLUDE DIRS**

- C:\OpenCV\OpneCV_bin\install\include
- C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include

***AND still I have errors:***

> unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::flip(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,int)"
>
> unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)"

What am I missing?

Comment: where did you "include" the libs? Are you compiling your project for x64 release mode? If debug mode, link the *d.lib versions of the libs instead.

Comment: feel free to write an answer with your solution and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to build the debug version of the OpenCV libs.

- opencv_highgui401d.lib
- opencv_core401d.lib
- opencv_videoio401d.lib